# Append hint with autotrace

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, hints, trace

I'm doing a direct-path insert which executes successfully. When I try to autotrace the execution, I get the `ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel`.

```
SQL> insert into emp_big select * from emp_big_temp;

411843 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.89

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3203427748

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |              |   357K|    45M|  1164   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | EMP_BIG      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL      | EMP_BIG_TEMP |   357K|    45M|  1164   (1)| 00:00:14 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         15  recursive calls
      31909  db block gets
      12829  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
   34685216  redo size
        845  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        802  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     411843  rows processed

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.18
SQL>
SQL> insert /*+ append */ into emp_big select * from emp_big_temp;

411843 rows created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.18

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
ERROR:
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel


SP2-0612: Error generating AUTOTRACE EXPLAIN report

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
       4438  db block gets
       4283  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
       7648  redo size
        829  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        816  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
     411843  rows processed
```

Questions:

1. Table `emp_big` has degree of parallelism set to 1, according to `select table_name, degree from user_tables`. Why does Oracle force parallel insert?
2. Why does using `autotrace trace` cause `ORA-12838`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the original output:**

This is not caused by autotrace. You will get the same error even without autotrace, just by repeating the same direct path insert. Issue a commit after the first insert.

This is a documented restriction: [ORA-12700 to ORA-19400](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e12700.htm)

> ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
>
> Cause: **Within the same transaction**, an attempt was made to add read or
> modification statements on a table after it had been modified in
> parallel **or with direct load**. This is not permitted.
>
> Action: Rewrite
> the transaction, or break it up into two transactions: one containing
> the initial modification and the second containing the parallel
> modification operation.

**Answer to the new output, after edit:**

Ok, so you have a rollback, and you started a new transaction. In this case, autotrace really is the culprit, indirectly. The above rule still applies, and as the above description says, even a read reference will cause the above error. If autotrace is enabled, it implicitly runs something like this (after your original statement was finished):

`EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID='PLUSxxxxxx' FOR insert /*+ append */ into emp_big select * from emp_big_temp;`

You can easily confirm this by enabling the errorstack trace for the error 12838 (it is fine in a sandbox environment for this short demo, but this is not how I would do this on a real database):

`alter system set events '12838 trace name errorstack level 3';`

If I run this now:

```
SQL> create table t1 as select * from dba_objects where 1=2;

Table created.

SQL> alter system set events '12838 trace name errorstack level 3';

System altered.

SQL> set autotrace on
SQL> insert /*+ append */ into t1 select * from dba_objects;

20079 rows created.


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
ERROR:
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

I will find the error and a trace file in the alert log. The trace file contains this:

```
dbkedDefDump(): Starting a non-incident diagnostic dump (flags=0x0, level=3, mask=0x0)
----- Error Stack Dump -----
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=5x12x8czsd3t9) -----
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID='PLUS730007' FOR insert /*+ append */ into t1 select * from dba_objects
```

And that is what causes the error, because it is still the same transaction. You can test it even without autotrace:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> set autotrace off
SQL> insert /*+ append */ into t1 select * from dba_objects;

20079 rows created.

SQL> explain plan for insert /*+ append */ into t1 select * from dba_objects;
explain plan for insert /*+ append */ into t1 select * from dba_objects
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel


SQL> select count(*) from t1;
select count(*) from t1
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

Comment: I neglected to show the `rollback` command between inserts. Output was edited in the original post.